# What is the IP address of computer/browser running applet?

Tags: java, applet, ip-address

If I run a digitally signed applet in a browser and connect to a 3rd party Web server, will that Web server identify the client using the IP address of the computer/browser running the applet or the IP address Server hosting the applet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The applet is running locally, it is just hosted on the server. So the IP address identified will be that of the computer/browser running the applet.

Answer (score 3):

You can't rely on the IP address reported by the applet, it will be the local IP
address of the browser's computer, which can be anything at all.

You also can't rely on the IP address presented at the connection to the server.  It
will be a valid address, but it's only a gateway address.  Commonly that's the gateway
from the applet's LAN to the public internet, but with port forwarding and proxies,
it can be almost anywhere.

One thing it will NOT be unless software there wants to make it so is the IP address
of the server host.

Comment: The Applet can also be on a machine with multiple IP addresses.

Answer (score 1):

The applet connects to the web server. The applet runs in the browser. So the Web server will see the TCP-Connection as coming from the browser (or any proxy that the client happens to use).